# R studio Error in cld function

Tags: r

When I run this code:

```
modf0ex_oss_subj <- lmer(ossf0exst ~ condition * group + age + gender + (1 | speaker) + (1 | item), data = subject_focus, REML = FALSE)
summary(modf0ex_oss_subj)
plot(allEffects(modf0ex_oss_subj))

# plot marginal means
marginal = lsmeans(modf0ex_oss_subj, ~ group:condition)
CLD = cld(marginal, alpha=0.05, Letters=letters, adjust="tukey")
CLD$.group=gsub(" ", "", CLD$.group)
```

I got this error:

> Error in cld(marginal, alpha = 0.05, Letters = letters, adjust =
> "tukey") :    could not find function "cld"

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `library(multcomp)`?

`cld` is in the `multcomp` package.

Try this example code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47015029/9136912) to check if your installation is correct:

```
library(multcomp)

Group1 <- c(12.4,10.7,11.9,11.0,12.4,12.3,13.0,12.5,11.2,11.1)
Group2 <- c(8.1,11.5,11.3,8.7,12.7,10.7,9.6,11.3,11.1,13.7)
Group3 <- c(8.5,11.6,10.2,10.9,9.0,9.6,9.9,11.3,10.5,14.2)
Group4 <- c(8.7,9.3,8.2,8.3,9.0,9.4,9.2,12.2,8.5,12.9)
Group5 <- c(12.7,13.2,11.8,11.9,12.2,11.2,13.7,11.8,11.5,9.7)

Combined_Groups<-data.frame(cbind(Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4,Group5))
Combined_Groups #shows spreadsheet like results
summary(Combined_Groups) #min, median, mean, max

Stacked_Groups <- stack(Combined_Groups)
Stacked_Groups #shows the table Stacked_Groups

Anova_Results<-aov(values~ind,data=Stacked_Groups)

ph <- glht(Anova_Results, linfct = mcp(ind = "Tukey"))
cld(ph)
```

I ran this code without a problem.

Comment: Yes, I did, and still he same error

Comment: Usually this error happens when a package is not properly called (library(multcomp)) or installed (install.packages("multcomp")). Check if the installation of multcomp is complete and up to date.
Try to run an example code that includes cld to check if it runs (I will put an example on my answer).

Comment: WOW! it runs! thank u soooo much. This is highly appreciated

Comment: Please mark my answer as Accepted :)